# Is there a way to link Autodesk Forge Buckets?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, autodesk-forge

I have created two buckets in the Autodesk Forge storage (`myprojectbucket` and `myscenariobucket`) but is there anyway I can link them together? For example, if I delete the `myprojectbucket` bucket, I would also like it to delete the `myscenariobucket` bucket. Is there a way for the program to identify which bucket is linked?

I have tried to differentiate them by having the `project` bucket act similar to a main project and the `scenario` bucket will act like a folder where files can be uploaded to.

**Project bucket**

```
{
    "bucketKey": "myprojectbucket",
    "createdDate": "1555586879197",
    "policyKey": "transient"
}
```

**Scenario bucket**

```
{
    "bucketKey": "myscenariobucket",
    "createdDate": "1555586121454",
    "policyKey": "transient"
}
```

**File inside Scenario bucket**

```
[
    {
        "bucketKey": "myscenariobucket",
        "objectId": "urn:adsk.objects:os.object:myscenariobucket/MyNewFile.txt",
        "objectKey": "MyNewFile.txt",
        "sha1": "6ebea95f436eca94a9e541878db7b37b01cc5300",
        "size": 23,
        "contentType": "application/octet-stream",
        "location": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/myscenariobucket/objects/MyNewFile.txt",
        "blockSizes": [],
        "deltas": [],
        "status": "OK"
    }
]
```

If I delete `myscenariobucket`, it should delete `MyNewFile.txt` file stored inside. This currently works as expected. However, if I delete `myprojectbucket`, I would like it to delete both `myscenariobucket` and `MyNewFile.txt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Forge buckets work like AWS S3 or Azure Objects. So you cannot expect to get one deleted one when another one is deleted. I noticed that you bucket policy is "policyKey": "transient", so your files will be deleted automatically after 24 hours. That means if you post a file in each bucket at the same time, they'll be both deleted 24 hours later.

Now, you could do the following to get the same result as your request; store your files like below with a prefix; so when the bucket gets deleted, everything is.

Get only one bucket

```
{
    "bucketKey": "mybucket",
    "createdDate": "1555586879197",
    "policyKey": "transient"
}
```

Store all files in it with a prefix scenario/ or project/

```
[
    {
        "bucketKey": "mybucket",
        "objectId": "urn:adsk.objects:os.object:mybucket/project/MyNewFile.txt",
        "objectKey": "project/MyNewFile.txt",
        "sha1": "6ebea95f436eca94a9e541878db7b37b01cc5300",
        "size": 23,
        "contentType": "application/octet-stream",
        "location": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/mybucket/objects/project/MyNewFile.txt",
        "blockSizes": [],
        "deltas": [],
        "status": "OK"
    },
    {
        "bucketKey": "mybucket",
        "objectId": "urn:adsk.objects:os.object:mybucket/scenario/MyNewFile.txt",
        "objectKey": "scenario/MyNewFile.txt",
        "sha1": "6ebea95f436eca94a9e541878db7b37b01cc5300",
        "size": 23,
        "contentType": "application/octet-stream",
        "location": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/mybucket/objects/scenario/MyNewFile.txt",
        "blockSizes": [],
        "deltas": [],
        "status": "OK"
    }
]
```

Hope that helps,